# Perl + how to read exported variable from the system ( Linux )

Tags: linux, bash, perl, export

The **FT_DIR** export variable in my Linux machine is":

```
# env | grep FT_DIR
FT_DIR=/opt/facebookDir2
```

or

```
echo $FT_DIR
/opt/facebookDir2
```

it is simple to read the FT_DIR exported variable from shell script example:

```
# more test.ksh 
#!/bin/ksh


echo $FT_DIR
```

run the script:

```
./test.ksh 
/opt/facebookDir2
```

but in Perl the story is different

```
more test.pl 

#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $FT_DIR = ` bash -c 'echo $FT_DIR' `  ;

print $FT_DIR;
```

run the script:

```
./test.pl
 Name "main::FT_DIR" used only once: possible typo at ./test.pl line 3.
 Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 3.
```

why **FT_DIR** in the Perl script isn’t /opt/facebookDir2 value

How to read the exported variable FT_DIR in Perl? , what need to fix in my Perl script

Comment: You should use `my $FT_DIR = $ENV{FT_DIR};`, no need to call out to bash

Comment: hi Arco , please put your solution as answer so I will vote for you

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to call out to `bash` to grab the environment variable, perl is capable of doing that itself.

Just use:

```
my $FT_DIR = $ENV{FT_DIR};
```